# Azure Pipeline do cleanup job when run is canceled or succeed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline which will run when I created a PR. The pipeline run will trigger some job on external service. And I have a cleanup stage at the end of the pipeline to cleanup the things deployed on external service. I only want cleanup work when it's successful. When it's failed, I don't want to do any cleanup so I can look into the error logs. When the pipeline succeeds, the cleanup job works fine.

Now I find that when I pushed a new commit to my feature branch, the previous run will be automatically canceled and a new run will start. Which makes sense. But as the pipeline is not success, it won't do cleanup. But I want the cleanup also be done when pipeline is canceled.

From the document, I find a pre-defined variable: Agent.JobStatus, it is the status of the build. Seems like the thing I'm looking for. But after test it seems not work.
I changed the job code like this, but it didn't work:

```
  - stage: Cleanup
    condition: always()
    dependsOn:
      - execution_stage
    variables:
      ExecutionSucceed: $[ stageDependencies.execution_stage.execution_job.outputs['execution_task.succeed'] ]
    jobs:
      - job: ...
        steps:
          - bash: |
              echo "Job status is $(Agent.JobStatus)"
              if [[ "$(ExecutionSucceed)" == 'True' || "$(Agent.JobStatus)" == "Canceled" ]]
              then
                # Do all the clean-up works
              fi
```

The output shows: Job status is Succeeded

Can someone help me to understand why it's succeeded, and how can I know the pipeline run is canceled?
Thanks

Comment: I think that your problem is that the job canceled is other execution and you don´t know the state for the actual execution. The job status never will be Canceled because the process is kill or skipped.Good Luck

Comment: Thank you @RobertoRamos , I actually tryed to cancel the run on pipeline web UI, and find the Agent.JobStatus is still Succeeded. Which is really confuse

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround , you can set the following condition:

```
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - script: echo Job A1
- stage: Cleanup
  condition: in(dependencies.A.result, 'Succeeded', 'Canceled')
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
    - script: echo Job B1
```

You can refer to the `Stage to stage dependencies` section in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#stage-to-stage-dependencies).

Comment: So the idea is, add one dummy stage just before cleanup. In a normal run it will always succeed, but when the pipeline run is canceled, the dummy stage's result is canceled, so we know the pipeline run status by the dummy stage result, right? That sounds a good idea and easy workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I find that could work but will be very difficult to actually use it in a pipeline. e.g. there are 10 stages before stage cleanup, then only the stage which is running when canceling happen will be Canceled result, all the others are Skipped. So for use that, I have to add all stages into the dependencies and check all stages' results in the condition. Do you have any other way?

Comment: As far as I know, there should be no easier way.

Comment: Thanks @Hugh Lin, I will make some more try to see if I can get anything better. Will update you if I find anything interesting